# Kotlin Gradle plugin version not supported

Tags: flutter, gradle

When I add these libraries, I get this problem when running, and I do not know the reason.

[image]

I tried a lot of searching, tried updating Gradle, and tried other additions, but the same error.

Why is this error and I want to know that? Please explain to me if someone has the solution

```
youtube_player_flutter:
dots_indicator:
flutter_svg:
build_runner:
dartz:
shared_preferences:
get_it:
easy_localization:
flutter_phoenix:
flutter_bloc:
equatable:
flutter_screenutil:
conditional_builder_null_safety:
json_serializable:
json_annotation:
floor:
floor_generator:
sqlite3_flutter_libs:
retrofit:
retrofit_generator:
dio:
pretty_dio_logger:
internet_connection_checker:
location:
geocoding:
wakelock:
url_launcher:
google_fonts:
sqflite:
video_player:
fluttertoast:
syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer:
advance_pdf_viewer:
```

Is there any objection between these libraries?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].